# Linking the same svg HTML

Tags: html, svg, server, request

I'm linking an SVG object in my HTML document. I link to the same SVG object multiple times. So on the first request it's making many GET requests to my server, where on the second pageview it's finally getting the SVG from cache.

Would it be possible so that on a first visit the SVG is only requested once and used in multiple object tags?

The following code is repeated many times on my webpage...

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="./html/backbutton.svg"></object>
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="./html/closebutton.svg"></object>
```

And results in this for first page views of the website...
[image]

Comment: load svg via js then set the objects data to svg via js

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response, this is exactly what I need.

Comment: plz mark answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

load svg via js then set the objects data to svg via js